# To close the app from particular page on single tap of hardware back button

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

My app consists of 2 pages called `login`, `home` and other lazy loaded `modules`. 
In the `app.component.ts`, condition is written such that if `localStorage` is empty it should route to `login` page else it should route to `home` page. Then from **home page user will routed other lazy loaded modules**

**app.component.ts**

```js
    import { Component } from '@angular/core';
    import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen/ngx';
    import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar/ngx';
    import { Platform, NavController } from '@ionic/angular';

    @Component({
      selector: 'app-root',
      templateUrl: 'app.component.html'
    })
    export class AppComponent {

      constructor(
        private splashScreen: SplashScreen,
        private statusBar: StatusBar,
        private platform: Platform,
        public navCtrl: NavController,
      ) {
        this.initializeApp();
        if (localStorage.getItem('token') !== null) {
          this.navCtrl.navigateRoot('/home');
        } else {
          this.navCtrl.navigateRoot('/login');
        }
      }

        initializeApp() {
          this.platform.ready().then(() => {
            this.statusBar.styleDefault();
            this.splashScreen.hide();
            this.platform.ready().then(() => {
            });
        });
      }


    }
```

**app-routing.module.ts**

```js
    import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
    import { PreloadAllModules, RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

    const routes: Routes = [

      {path: 'home',loadChildren: './home/home.module#HomePageModule'},
      { path: 'login', loadChildren: './login/login.module#LoginPageModule' },
      { path: '', loadChildren: './nav-bar/nav-bar.module#NavBarPageModule' },  <===== Lazy loaded module
      { path: '', loadChildren: './nav-bar-provider/nav-bar-provider.module#NavBarProviderPageModule' }, <===== Lazy loaded module
    ];

    @NgModule({
      imports: [
        RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { preloadingStrategy: PreloadAllModules })
      ],
      exports: [RouterModule]
    })
    export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

This condition works fine. Then in the `home` page I have written code to exit from the app on **double-tap** as shown below:

**home.page.ts**

```js
    import { Component , OnInit} from '@angular/core';
    import { Platform } from '@ionic/angular';
    @Component({
      selector: 'app-home',
      templateUrl: 'home.page.html',
      styleUrls: ['home.page.scss'],
    })
    export class HomePage implements OnInit {
      subscription;
      constructor(public platform: Platform) {}

      ngOnInit() {}

      ionViewDidEnter() {
        this.subscription = this.platform.backButton.subscribe(() => {
          (navigator as any).app.exitApp();
        });
      }
      ionViewDidLeave() {
        this.subscription.unsubscribe();
      }
    }
```

Now the issues is: `On double tap in home page,the app will close, But on single tap it will routed 1st lazy loaded module(i,e NavBarPageModule). How can avoid this?` For this issue, I tried giving `router-path` to lazy loaded modules like this:

```js
    const routes: Routes = [

      {path: 'home',loadChildren: './home/home.module#HomePageModule'},
      { path: 'login', loadChildren: './login/login.module#LoginPageModule' },
      { path: 'nav-bar', loadChildren: './nav-bar/nav-bar.module#NavBarPageModule' }, 
      { path: 'nav-bar-provider', loadChildren: './nav-bar-provider/nav-bar-provider.module#NavBarProviderPageModule' },
    ];
```

Then I was unable to route to `lazy loaded modules` from `home` page.

I just want to close the app from `home page` on single tap.

Comment: can you share how exactly you achieve binding to double tap? hammer.js? This can help help you;) Also what is the intended end state - what should happen on single tap if on home page?

Comment: In the home page on single-tap of backbutton the app should close.

Comment: Can u please share login method. like click funtion for login. after that, I'll provide you any solution.

Comment: In the login page, On clicking a button `called`, I will just call this method **public onLogin() {
    this.navCtrl.navigateRoot('/home');
   }** Then the user will be routed to `home` page.

Comment: did you tried using ionViewWillLeave instead of ionViewDidLeave?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
document.addEventListener('backbutton', function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  navigator.app.exitApp(); // exit the app
});
```

I hope this will help you.

Answer (score 2):

I am posting the `solution` which worked for me, It may help for other users.

**app.component.ts** file should look like this:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Platform, ToastController } from '@ionic/angular';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: 'app.component.html'
})
export class AppComponent {
  counter = 0;

  constructor(
              public platform: Platform,
              public toastController: ToastController
  ) { 
    this.platform.ready().then(() => {
      document.addEventListener('backbutton', async () => {
          if (this.counter === 0) {
            this.counter++;
            this.alertToast();
            setTimeout(() => { this.counter = 0; }, 3000);
          } else {
            (navigator as any).app.exitApp();
          }
      });
    });
  }

  async alertToast() {
    const toast = await this.toastController.create({
      message: 'Press again to exit',
      duration: 300,
      position: 'middle',
    });
    toast.present();
  }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this snippet which uses Ionic 4 and browser APIs:

```
if (this.platform.is("android")) {
    this.platform.backButton.subscribe(() => {
        if (window.location.pathname === "/home") {
            navigator['app'].exitApp();
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1)Import the IonRouterOutlet in your component

```
import { IonRouterOutlet } from '@ionic/angular';
```

2) adding Viewchildren

```
  @ViewChildren(IonRouterOutlet) routerOutlets: QueryList<IonRouterOutlet>;
```

3)And finally writing code in your component

this.platform.backButton.subscribe(async () => {

```
this.routerOutlets.forEach((outlet: IonRouterOutlet) => {
  if (this.router.url.match('/home')) {
            navigator['app'].exitApp(); // work for ionic 4
  };
```

})
});

Comment: sorry for the late reply, I have tried this solution too. Still the same issue.